# Basic requirejs concept needed to make work musicjson package

Tags: javascript, requirejs, xmldom

I'd like to use the musicjson.js package that helps to convert musicXML files into json notation, looking if it's a good way to import for example exported musicXML Finale scores into a browser playing with the Fermata/VexFlow class.

https://github.com/saebekassebil/musicjson

The thing is that this module works with require (calling for 
nodes packages like fs) and I'm just a newbee in requirejs...Even if I spent few time in understanding the tutorial in the website, I don't still get how to solve this kind of basic problem when the dependencies of my musicjson.js need to be called like :

```
var xmldom   = require('flat-xmldom'),
fs = require('fs'),
path = require('path'),
util = require('util');
```

My index.php page does the classic require call:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <head>

     <!-- javascript head -->
    <!-- REQUIRE -->
    <script data-main="scripts/main" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>

</head>

  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

In my scripts/main.js, I'd like to do simply what it is told from musicjon :

```
var music = require('musicjson');
music.musicJSON(xml, function(err, json) {
// Do something with the MusicJSON data
});
```

I putted also, in the same directory scripts/, the flat-xmldom folder, fs.js, path.js, util.js

When I do this, I've just obtain this classic error of : 
***Error: Module name "musicjson" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])***

...That looks like a common error referenced in the requirejs website,
but if I try things that I guess it should be written, I get a bit lost to determine where is the fundamental conceptual mistake here :

```
require.config({
   baseUrl: '/scripts/',
   paths: {
    flatxmldom:'./flat-xmldom/__package__',
    fs: 'fs',
    path:'path',
    util:'util',
    musicjson: 'musicjson'
   }
});
require(['flatxmldom','fs','path','util','musicjson'],function(flatxmldom,fs,path,util,musicjson){})
```

Error returned in this case for example : 
***Module name "fs" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])***

Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: Looks like you're mixing browser Javascript with node.js code; your browser has no access to node.js modules (`fs`, `path`, etc.). Moreover, musicjson seems to depend on node.js explicitly so you will have a hard time trying to satisfy its dependencies in a browser. More info: http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link. So apparently, like I said below, maybe it's possible to extract from the musicjson.js and the flatxmldom packages the ParserMusicXML and ParserMusicJSON functions (and all their sub functions) in order to put them in a client-side possible js. I'm on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is not a RequireJS problem per-se. The package you want to use is a Node.js package.  It is intended to run in node (a server/desktop execution environment for JavaScript).  It cannot/will not run in web page in a browser.

The packages it is trying to use (fs in particular) provide access to system resources such as the file system.  Node provides these packages as part of its core libraries to any package that runs in node.  A browser is specifically designed for security reasons never to allow direct access to such resources to any code that run in the browser because who knows where it came from or might try to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's right, this is something that I was about to realized few minutes after posting...Conceptually understanding js for node backend and js for the browser... So, now, I'm trying just to pick up the functions inside musicjson.js/flatxml-dom/ and trying to build my customized client-side scoreMusicXMLParser.js.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really tried to do this myself, but browserify (alternative to requirejs) claims that it will allow you to use any node package in your application.

If musicjson is at the heart of what your app should achieve and requirejs is a small step on the way to getting there, you could try your luck with browserify instead.